# DRF Project Static Files Problem On Server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to host the project I prepared on PythonAnywhere. Even though I run the `collectstatic` command, I can't get any results. When I visit the url, the design does not appear, the same is true for the Admin. When I looked, the requested address is `static` file instead of `static_base`. But `static_url` and `static_root` should have different names anyway. Do I need to add something related to this field in the urls.py file? Because I haven't seen anything like it when I read it.

[image]

**Settings.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'key'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ],
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME" : timedelta(minutes = 15)
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["talhakoylu.pythonanywhere.com"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "rest_framework",
    "book",
    "country",
    "account",
    "school",
    "nested_inline",
    "quiz"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr-tr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/talhakoylu/BookOrBooks/bookorbooks/static_base'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)


MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.CustomUser'
```

Comment: What is the url and what is the response for a static file? (and is it present in settings.STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: @thebjorn `2021-08-01 21:36:01,849: Not Found: /static/rest_framework/js/default.js` This is the error that appears in the log, normally it should start as `static_base`, even though I changed it in settings.py, nothing changes. In `static_base` the files are available.

Comment: Are you running this through manage.py runserver or on a "real" server?

Comment: @thebjorn real server

Comment: Then you need to configure it to serve static files. Django settings are not involved.

Comment: Take a look at PythonAnywhere specific instructions on https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/